# Windmill: A Masyu Puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, masyu

The standard [Masyu](https://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/masyu.html) rules apply.

[image]

Comment: Penpa link for solvers: https://git.io/JOnFI

Comment: @athin the rule link appears to be broken

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution

> [image]

Step 1

> Start with some basic deductions concerning circles that are next to a wall.
>  [image]

Step 2

> Notice that we can't go through the white circles in rows 4 or 9 without making a loop so these must be crossed horizontally. Additionally, this forces the path descending from the top of column 3 to go left since going right would also force an issue in the top left corner. We can develop in the top left to get the following
>  [image]

Step 3

> If the path goes through the black circle in row 4 to the left, then a little bit of development leads us to the following untenable position.
>  [image]
>  Hence, it must be that it goes to the right through this circle. Some more development in that region leads us to the following,
>  [image]

Step 4

> If the path continues from the black circle in row 7 to the left, we can develop and get to the following untenable position.
>  [image]
>  Hence, the path must continue to the right from the black circle in row 7 and some more development leads us to the following position.
>  [image]

Step 5

> From here, we see that the path must go horizontally after traversing the white circle in row 4. The deductions from there are reasonably straight forward.
>  [image]

Comment: Great job and well done! You might need to point out why are they "untenable positions", especially the subtle one on Step 3 :) (and also FYI, black circle on line 6 has similar logic to the one on line 7 -- if that's somewhat helpful too for other solvers as well!)